# remove spaces from logged filename

Tags: linux, sed

On a linux machine I'm trying to remove spaces from some log entries that detail a list of files.

IE: /path/to/some/file has spaces.file

However there is a lot of other text in those lines where I want to the white space to remain for consistent formatting.

I tried using sed, but I'm very unfamiliar with how to structure the regex.

```
sed -e 's/ *\/\.//g' file.log
```

Comment: can you show some fragment of that file?

Comment: Tue Mar 14 06:15:20 2017 62065 /EXTRACTS/Principal Payments - 03072017 - 2 - 64606 - EN.PDF

There will be stuff after the file extension as well that I don't want removed.

Comment: now, the same line but after replacement, please

Comment: Tue Mar 14 06:15:20 2017 62065 /EXTRACTS/PrincipalPayments-03072017-2-64606-EN.PDF

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With sed, to remove spaces after first `/` found:

```
sed ':a;s/\(\/[^ ]*\) /\1/;ta;' file.log
```

**How it works:**

- `\(\/[^ ]*\)`: after first `/`, non space characters are captured up to(but excluding) next space. The capturing group is output using backreference.
- `ta`:  if previous substitution succeeds, `ta` loops to label `a` to process remaining spaces

**Edit:**

To removes spaces from `/` up to next `.`:

```
sed ':a;s/\(\/[^ .]*\) /\1/;ta;' file.log
```

or in ERE mode to avoid escaping brackets:

```
sed -r ':a;s/(\/[^ .]*) /\1/;ta;' file.log
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed

```
sed -r ':a;s#(.*/.*) #\1#;ta' file.log
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Comment: is there anyway to get it to stop removing spaces once it encounters a period/dot? This works, but it removes the spaces after the file extension which causes me to miss other valuable information.

Comment: echo Tue Mar 14 06:15:20 2017 62065 /EXTRACTS/Principal Payments - 03072017 - 2 - 64606 - EN.PDF a b c |sed -r ':a;s#(.*/[^.]*) #\1#;ta'

Comment: @AlexCarman You may see here some similarity with my answer. Feel free to test it.